# Migrating from JBoss AS 7.1 to JBoss EAP 7.3.0

Tags: hibernate, deployment, jboss, jboss-eap-7

We are migrating from **Jboss AS 7.1** to **Jboss EAP 7.3.0** and we are getting the below error:

```
<<
22:36:16,304 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ejb-application.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ejb-application.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "ejb-application.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:73)
    ... 10 more
>>
```

here is our Persistence.xml file

```
<<
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="jboss">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed
         data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/hibernate-quickstart-ds.xml, you
         can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/hibernate-quickstart-ds.xml -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jdbc/AppDatasource</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
>>
```

We understand it is something to do with persistence.xml & jboss-deployment-structure.xml files.
We tried to include/exclude all the relevant modules in the files, but still we are getting the above issue.
Also, we are migrating from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5.

Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be packaging Hibernate along with your application in a different version or you excluded the Hibernate version in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml